# How to read and divide individual lines of a file in python?

Tags: python, file, buffer

Thanks to stackoverflow, I am able to read and copy a file. However, I need to read a picture file one line at a time, and the buffer array can't exceed 3,000 integers. How would I separate the lines, read them, and then copy them? Is that the best way to execute this?

Here is my code, courtesy of @Chayim:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import readline

source = raw_input("Enter source file path: ")
dest = raw_input("Enter destination path: ")

file1 = open(source,'r')


if not os.path.isfile(source):
    print "Source file %s does not exist." % source
    sys.exit(3)
    file_line = infile.readline()

try:
    shutil.copy(source, dest)

    infile = open(source,'r')
    outfile = open(dest,'r')

    file_contents = infile.read()
    file_contents2 = outfile.read()

    print(file_contents)
    print(file_contents2)

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

except IOError, e:
    print "Could not copy file %s to destination %s" % (source, dest)
    print e
    sys.exit(3)
```

I added 
    file_line = infile.readline()
but I'm concerned that infile.readline() will return a string, instead of integers. Also, how do I limit the number of integers it processes?

Comment: What is your question/problem specifically? what do you want the above program to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
infile = open(source,'r')

file_contents_lines = infile.readlines()

for line in file_contents_lines:
    print line
```

This will get you all the lines in the file and put them into a list containing each line as an element in the list.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) here.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely take a look at the doc.